# Get date time of dropdown menu value and add it together with text Box date time

Tags: javascript, php, html

*Good morning.*

I have a project going on, which is built with 2 textBox, 1 Button, 1 Dropdown menu.

The first textBox has the function to choose a date time. The second textBox **should** get the result of the calculation by clicking the button.

**Function:**

The user typed in a date time, now he can choose an option in the dropdown menu. Now he can press the button to calculate a date time. The calculation should always add 3 years to the date time. I did the function in **javascript** like that:

```
var fristJahr;
var hFvg;
var hFdatum;
var jahr;
var monat;
var tag;
var fristMonat;
var fristTag;
var frist = new Date();

if (fs.event.eventCode === 'H34' || fs.event.eventCode === 'H06') {
    var mydate = fs.event.eventDate;
    mydate.setFullYear(mydate.getFullYear() + 1);
    mydate.setMonth(11);
    mydate.setDate(31);
    // fs.showHint(mydate, 'caption?');
    var newdate = new Date(mydate.getFullYear(), mydate.getMonth(), mydate.getDate());
    fs.event.cCase.limitationDate = newdate;

}


hFvg = fs.event.eventCode;

if (hFvg === 'H17' || hFvg === 'H18' || hFvg === 'H19' || hFvg === 'H20' || hFvg === 'H21') {
    hFdatum = fs.event.eventDate;
    jahr = (hFdatum.getFullYear());
    monat = (hFdatum.getMonth());
    tag = (hFdatum.getDate());

    fristMonat = monat + 6;
    if (fristMonat > 12) {
        fristMonat = fristMonat - 12;
        fristJahr = jahr + 1;
    } else {
        fristMonat = fristMonat;
        fristJahr = jahr;
    }

    // Tagesdatum erhöhen
    fristTag = tag + 1;

    // sicherstellen, das ein gültiges Datum entstehen würde
    if (fristMonat === 1 && fristTag > 31) {
        fristMonat = 2;
        fristTag = 1;
    }
    if (fristMonat === 2 && fristTag > 28) {
        fristMonat = 3;
        fristTag = 1;
    }
    if (fristMonat === 4 && fristTag > 30) {
        fristMonat = 5;
        fristTag = 1;
    }
    if (fristMonat === 6 && fristTag > 30) {
        fristMonat = 7;
        fristTag = 1;
    }
    if (fristMonat === 7 && fristTag > 31) {
        fristMonat = 8;
        fristTag = 1;
    }
    if (fristMonat === 9 && fristTag > 30) {
        fristMonat = 10;
        fristTag = 1;
    }
    if (fristMonat === 11 && fristTag > 30) {
        fristMonat = 12;
        fristTag = 1;
    }


    frist.setDate(fristTag);
    frist.setFullYear(fristJahr);
    frist.setMonth(fristMonat);
    //frist.get
    //frist.toDateString()
    //    fs.event.cCase.limitationDate = frist.getFullYear() + '-' + frist.getMonth()+1 +'-' + frist.getDate();
    var neueFrist = new Date(frist.getFullYear(), frist.getMonth(), frist.getDate());
    //neueFrist.setFullYear();
    fs.event.cCase.limitationDate = neueFrist;

}
```

what I already have now in **PHP** and **HTML**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="demo.css">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <style type="text/css">
         .mt10px{
         margin-top: 10px;
         }
         .mt20px{
         margin-top: 20px;
         }
         .input{
         background: #ffffff;
         border: 1px solid #cccccc;
         border-radius: 3px;
         padding: 6px 4px;
         }
         p{
         line-height: 25px;
         }
      </style>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/date-time-picker.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form method="POST" action="">
         <table align="center" border="1">
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td width="250">
                     <input type="text" class="mt10px input" id="J-demo-01" name="datum">
                     <script type="text/javascript">
                        $('#J-demo-01').dateTimePicker();

                     </script>
                     <select>
                     <?php
                        require("require.php");

                        $oMy = new clsMYSQL();

                        $oMy->Query("select * from IKE_EventTemplate where EventCode like 'H%' and 
                        Variant='H' order by EventCode ASC");

                        while(!$oMy->eof)
                        {                        
                        echo "<option>";
                        echo  $oMy->row['EventCode'];
                        echo "</option>";    
                        $oMy->Move();
                        }
                        ?>
                     </select>
                  </td>
                  <td> <input name="bgBerechne" type="submit" value="Berechne"></td>
                  <?php
                     $datum= $_POST['datum'];
                     echo "<td width='250'><input type='text' class='mt10px input' id='J-demo- 
                     07' value=$datum></td>";
                     ?>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </form>
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

[How it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psB7f.png)

My code in PHP already copies the value of the textBox where you can choose your date time, but it shouldn't just copy the value, it should post the solution of the date time and dropdown menu function.

Can someone give me a hint how I can help myself? 
Thank you for your time :)!

Comment: Your PHP code just taking `$datum= $_POST['datum'];` one of your textbox value alone, where are the other 2?

Comment: My PHP code is just taking the value (date time) from one textBox and paste it into the second textBox. My PHP code doesn't have other functions to calculate 3 years to the date time which the user entered. Thats why I made this thread. I am lost and don't know how to make the other functions in PHP. I'm new in PHP so I'm trying to figure out how to learn to make such things.

Comment: If you have already calculated the Datetime with 3 years and copied to the 2nd textbox then post that textbox values as well to the PHP page

Comment: No I didn't do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) for the functionality you need, here it adds 3 years to the given date. [Check here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bca9be4759fea3d598b10fe3be5180860f0a9b70)

```
<?php

$date = '2018-09-20 11:07:00';
$date_after_three_years = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);
$date_after_three_years ->modify('+3 years');

echo $date_after_three_years ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

?>
```

After comment:

Bind any javascript function that does an AJAX request to the PHP code which fetches the DateTime value from database for the corresponding dropdown value.

For e.g.

**HTML**

```
<select "onchange=getValueFromDatabase(this)"></select>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function getValueFromDatabase(thisObj)
{
    var selected = thisObj.value;
    var postData = {
          "action": "get_dropdown_value_from_db",
          "search_param": selected
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: 'your_code.php',
      method: 'POST',
      data: postData,
      success: function(result)
      {
         if (result) //then use the value, maybe for your case bind it to the textbox
      },
      error: function(jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown)
      {
      } 
    });
}
```

**PHP**

```
require("require.php");

if (isset($_POST["action"]) && $_POST["action"] == "get_dropdown_value_from_db")
{
   echo getDropDownValue($_POST["search_param"]); //here you're gettign back the value which you posted from AJAX
   die(); //stopping further execution to the code which is not needed at this point
}

function getDropDownValue($value)
{
   $returnValue = "";

   $oMy = new clsMYSQL();
   $oMy->Query("query to fetch datetime where drop down value ='"+ $value +"'");

   while(!$oMy->eof)
   {                        
       $returnValue = $oMy->row['COLUMN_NAME'];
       $oMy->Move();
   }

   return $returnValue;
}
```

Hope this helps. Anyhow, this is just a basic idea, always when writing queries you need to use the parameterized query with [PreparedStatement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: Thank you, that helped me alot. But how can I get the value of a database table which is connected with my dropdown menu. With your solution I can add 3 years on the date time, which I asked for, but I also want to get a date time from a database by clicking a dropdown menu, which is already connected to the database by my code.

Comment: What you need exactly? Your dropdown values are already binding from the database. Do you want to get some value from the database when you choose an option from the dropdown?

Comment: " Do you want to get some value from the database when you choose an option from the dropdown?" Exactly thats what I want

Comment: @BurnePapurn, Check my edited answer and hope that helps

Comment: Is there any possible chance to replace the javascript code ? Because its a issue caused by sql injections. But really really thank you! You helped me a lot

Comment: @BurnePapurn, You don't need to change javascript code here instead you should PHP code which is not parameterized to avoid SQL Injection

Comment: so you posted a javascript and a php code and the php code is the replacement of the javascript code

Comment: Both Javascript and PHP code are needed for the dropdown functinality to work